# PHP Performance: passing data using GET/POST or retrieve in $_SESSION session.

Tags: php, performance, session, web-traffic

The question is : Is retrieving data from POST/GET parameters faster than using SESSION?

Details:
1. When a user submit a form (not Ajax) from view, currently, it is directed to a script that acts as a controller. In this script, it will call session_start() at the beginning, and it will retrieve one parameter, "userid" for later use, then redirect the user to a different page using header("Location: "). The session handler is set to "files" (default). I am thinking to replace this with passing the "userid" as a POST parameter instead. Is this going to improve performance?

P.S the webapp is hitting an issue which the session data is "lost" during high traffic (~ 1000 concurrent users), however this lost is intermittent and occurred in most of the users. I am trying to optimize it within a given set of server specs.

Thanks

Comment: around 100 users got through the webapp without any trouble

Answer (score 0):

SESSION means that files are located on server.
POST/GET means that data comes from user directly through networking.

The main problem will be if you send "userid" using POST/GET is a security problem. That means, that anyone can send any "userid", and send a form from  any user of your system.

Comment: Yes, i do realize the security problem, thanks! But which one is more "reliable" under high traffic?

Comment: If you are asking about network traffic, so it will be more data sending to server using POST/GET userid.
And SESSION will use only harddisk

Comment: Can you tell what a "controller script" looks like? 
Is it written only for one job or there a lot of code with initialization etc. ?

Comment: the controller script takes that userid and query the database and then insert a record.Finally redirect the user to a different view script. It is basically written for one job.

Comment: I see...
So try it, watch the difference.
Maybe the encrypting can solve the security problem with POST/GET userid?